# Microsoft Graph API callRecords Subscription not receiving notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am currently evaluating Microsoft Teams Graph API endpoints for us and our customers. Our goal would be to compile a list of past callRecords for a specific user.
Since the API does not (currently) offer an endpoint to just fetch a list of past/done callRecords we need to subscribe to the /communications/callRecords notifications.

Using the example project specified in the documentation ( https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) we successfully created subscriptions and were also able to update these subscriptions (not part of the example project).
I am running the example project on my local machine using ngrok as suggested.

So far everything works, but we do not get any notification. I made various calls with the Teams Desktop App using the same user that gave admin consent for accessing callRecords but I never received a notification on any test subscription.

The current active subscription in question is "07b23247-66d9-46b9-ac67-a72d5d702628" and was created around 2020-09-09T09:20:00.000Z (I do not have the precise minute/seconds). It since then has also been successfully renewed.
Here is an extract of the subscription creation response:

```
{
  '@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions/$entity',
  id: '07b23247-66d9-46b9-ac67-a72d5d702628',
  resource: '/communications/callRecords',
  changeType: 'created',
  expirationDateTime: '2020-09-12T07:20:09.036Z'
}
```

I do monitor all incoming traffic using ngroks http://127.0.0.1:4040 endpoint and so far I only received the validationToken requests. That tells me that the endpoint does indeed receive requests.

I am currently at a loss as where to look further for an error on my side.

I opened this stack overflow is as it is the requested action to take according to the troubleshoot section of the example project (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md).

Comment: I saw that the "changeType" was set to created only so i created a second subscription with changeType set to 'created,updated', but that does not seem to solve the issue...

Second Subscription: 7ca9d047-c134-41c1-b847-73a5a8417bf3 (created around 2020-09-09T11:20:00.000Z)

Comment: We could not repro the issue on our side. I tried the [C# sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#creating-the-subscription) for the same and i was able to create a subscription and listen to the call Records notification. Could you please check if you are able to receive notifications for mails/new messages in channel?

Comment: I tried creating another subscription using the App-Only flow for resource "me/mailFolders(\'Inbox\')/messages" but i get:
"Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The requested user 'xyz' is invalid.]"

i then tried the same for resource "me/events" with the same error response.
which is weird because i can use outlook to ream and write mails and use the calendar.

when using the other flow I get asked for a security code during login (like always) but in that flow i never get the code send to my other email account, so i cannot login.

Comment: managed to get a "me/events" subscription with delegated auth, but so far i do not get any notifications when creating calendar events on the endpoint. But it also says "latency: unknown" in the documentation, so i'll wait

Do i need a "special" account? is using subscriptions paid only?

Comment: Are you trying to create a subscription for callrecords or events?

Comment: My goal is to have a callRecord history stored in my database. For that i need a working subscription for callRecords but that does not work. I assumed your last comment was to check other types of subscriptions: "Could you please check if you are able to receive notifications for mails/new messages in channel?". I do not know what "mails/new messages in channel?" means but I tried a subscription for events to see if that works. You know, to see if subscriptions work for me in general... But it also does not work.

Comment: My endpoint is not being called for any type of notification for that I have an active subscription. I do not see any attempt made towards my server in the access logs besides for token validation when creating a subscription. For most subscriptions I get rejected with obscure error when creating them. But creating a callRecords subscription works with no notifications being send as well as an events subscription, again with no notifications being send.

Comment: Since I am not even receiving anything at the server before the code is being called I currently have to assume that my subscriptions do not produce any notifications. And I want to know why. But in the end I only need callRecords subscriptions.

Comment: We tried this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#creating-the-subscription) to create and subscribe to notifications and we could not repro the issue. Could you please check if this works for you else please send out an email to microosftteamsdevATmicrosoft.com and we can connect over call.

Comment: As per the MS documentation there is a latency in the `/communications/callRecords` subscription. callRecord latency: (Average latency) Less than 15 minutes AND (Maximum latency) 60 minutes. How much time did you wait on your subscription link for the conclusion of no event?